# For Loop Return to Top of Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am an excel vba novice and I am trying to write some code to automate a specific task. I managed to find the code below and customized it to suite my needs. The code, activated by the command button, will look through column I for text FALSE starting with row 5. When it encounters a FALSE, it will stop and copy the cell in column C on the same row.

The code works for that purpose, but I would like to take it a step further. If the code reaches the last filled cell in the I column without encountering a FALSE, I would like it to go back to the top of the column and search starting with I1.

Is there a way to do something like this with a For Loop? I have been looking at Do Until and Do While loops but haven't seen an example that resembles what I am trying to do.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[Picture of the Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aml3m.jpg)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LR = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 5 To LR
            With .Range("I" & i)
                If .Text = ("FALSE") Then
                    .Offset(0, -6).Copy
                Exit For
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Then why not `For i = 1 To LR`? also where are you pasting after `.Copy`?

Comment: Probably could use the `Range.Find` instead of brute force iteration...

Comment: The program is a little unique. The values in column C represent an ordered list of employees that have to be assigned work in the specific order from top to bottom with one work item at a time. The FALSE values represent employees who are present for work and TRUE represents employees who are absent. I want the code to look for the next FALSE on the list in sequence (next available employee). In my final worksheet, there will be 10 command buttons. The first will use For i = 2 to LR, the second will use For i = 3 to LR and so on until the last button where I will use For i = 1 to LR.

Comment: The data that gets copied will be pasted into a different program outside of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare some boolean variable: `Dim isFound As Boolean`, set it to false: `isFound = False`, if match is found, then set it to true: `isFound = True` (right after copying value). After `For` loop check if match was found `If isFound Then...` and check the remaining 5 cells: from `I1` to `I5` (because in preceding loop we checked the rest) or you can just add another loop which will go throguh `I` column.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your help!